# Integrating a Virtual Machine in WinRT

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, windows-runtime, task

I have a virtual machine in C# that has two constructor overloads, five event handlers, and two public properties. I have integrated this VM in WinForms and Silverlight apps and even used it in a client/server setting as a web application.

The interface is as follows:

Constructors

```
public Engine(Stream gameFile) { .. }
public Engine(Stream gameFile, Stream saveFile) { .. }
```

Events

```
public OutputReady(object sender, OutputReadyEventArgs e);
public LineWanted(object sender, LineWantedEventArgs e);
public KeyWanted(object sender, KeyWantedEventArgs e);
public SaveRequested(object sender, SaveRestoreEventArgs e);
public LoadRequested(object sender, SaveRestoreEventArgs e);
```

Properties

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ChanneData { get; set; }
public byte[] SaveData { get; set; }
```

When implementing this in WinForms and Silverlight, I had to use Invoke or similar to write to the UI thread.

In WinRT, the switching between UI and background thread is hidden behind async/await and Task handling and I haven't really been able to port my VM the way I want to....which as a service.

I can embed the vm in the MainForm of my application as I have done in Silverlight, but I want a more MVC/Service implementation. I'd like to remove the VM to a service that has a simple interface for starting a game, sending in new commands, saving games, and loading games. The MainForm shouldn't know anything about the vm implementation.

I've worked around this for more than a few hours and still don't have a clear enough understanding of async/await and Tasks to do it so that it works properly. I can get the engine started and send in commands, but save and load fail and I think this is because the async stuff is not working properly.

WinForms simple implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

using FyreVM;

namespace FyreVMTest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Thread vmThread = null;
        private Engine vm = null;
        private AutoResetEvent inputReadyEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private string command = "";

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream stream =
                 assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FyreVMTest.Game.shadow-w8.ulx");
            vm = new Engine(stream);

            vm.KeyWanted += vm_KeyWanted;
            vm.LineWanted += vm_LineWanted;
            vm.LoadRequested += vm_LoadRequested;
            vm.OutputReady += vm_OutputReady;
            vm.SaveRequested += vm_SaveRequested;

            vmThread = new Thread(VMThreadProc);
            vmThread.IsBackground = true;
            vmThread.Start();
        }

        private void VMThreadProc(object dummy)
        {
            try
            {
                vm.Run();
                this.Invoke(new Action(GameFinished));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void GameFinished()
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void RequestLine()
        {
            CommandLine.Focus();
        }

        private void vm_LineWanted(object sender, LineWantedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(RequestLine));
            inputReadyEvent.WaitOne();
            e.Line = command;
        }

        private void vm_KeyWanted(object sender, KeyWantedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Invoke(new Action(RequestKey));
            //inputReadyEvent.WaitOne();
            //e.Char = entry[0];
        }

        private void vm_OutputReady(object sender, OutputReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<Dictionary<string,string>>(HandleOutput), e.Package);
        }

        private void vm_SaveRequested(object sender, SaveRestoreEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Stream = (Stream)this.Invoke(new Func<Stream>(RequestSaveStream));
        }

        private void vm_LoadRequested(object sender, SaveRestoreEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Stream = (Stream)this.Invoke(new Func<Stream>(RequestLoadStream));
        }

        private Stream RequestSaveStream()
        {
            using (SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Select Save File";
                dlg.Filter = "Textfyre save files (*.tfq)|*.tfq";

                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    return new FileStream(dlg.FileName,
                                    FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
                }
            }
        }

        private Stream RequestLoadStream()
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                dlg.Title = "Load a Saved Game";
                dlg.Filter = "Textfyre save files (*.tfq)|*.tfq";

                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    return new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                }
            }
        }

        private void HandleOutput(Dictionary<string, string> package)
        {
            MainOutput.Clear();
            foreach (string key in package.Keys)
            {
                MainOutput.AppendText(key + ": " + package[key]);
            }

        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            command = CommandLine.Text;
            CommandLine.Text = "";
            inputReadyEvent.Set();
        }

    }
}
```

So I'm looking for guidance on how to implement this in WinRT. Is the interface a problem or do I need to change it to be more WinRT friendly? If it is okay, what's the best way to implement this in a class and then how do I call the class from a MainForm?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it helps, a sample non-working project is here: https://github.com/ChicagoDave/FyreXaml/

Answer (score 0):

Invoking on the UI thread in WinRT is similar to Silverlight in that you use a Dispatcher. In this case it is a [`CoreDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.aspx).

There are a few ways to access it, but the best is likely:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher
```

Note: You can only access it that way after the launch of the app. If you do any VM initialization pre-launch, you will likely get a null reference.

What I suggest doing is creating a custom `Dispatcher` class which has a virtual `Invoke` method. Create a subclass of that which accepts a `CoreDispatcher` property. In the `Invoke` method, if the `CoreDispatcher` is `null`, just `Invoke` the `Action` (or `Function`), otherwise `Invoke` it on the `CoreDispatcher`.

Then you are free to create a portable `Dispatcher` accessor in a PCL or other component library and have your app inject a new `Dispatcher` object into it (Inversion of Control at its best).

To get you started:

```
// In your PCL
public abstract class PortableDispatcher
{
    public abstract void Invoke(Action action);
}

// In your app
public class WinRTDispatcher : PortableDispatcher
{
    public override void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.
            RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new DispatchedHandler(action);
    }
}
```

Then in your PCL, you have one `static ViewModelLocator`. Give it a property of type `PortableDispatcher`. When starting your app, set the property in the Locator to a new `WinRTDispatcher`. Anyone that wants to dispatch to the UI thread from the PCL does so through the `ViewModelLocator`'s `PortableDispatcher`. Thanks to the injected object, they get to access the WinRT `CoreDispatcher` without having to know anything about it!

Comment: Yeah I'm still struggling with dependency injection. I mostly get it, but I'll have to fumble around with your suggestion for few days. But thanks...I _think_ I know what you mean.

Comment: Added an additional example to get you started.

Comment: Look at the github project and tell me if I'm on the right track. I moved my vm code to a PCL along with the PortableDispatcher class. The MainForm sets the WinRTDispatcher on the service and loads the service.